# How to Find a Weighing Matrix of Size n?

Tags: matrix, probability-or-statistics, algorithm

Weighting matrices appear in the statistical design of experiments ([Weighting Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighing_matrix) and [Statistical Design of Experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_experiments#Example).

A weighting matrix is a generalization of Hadamard matrices, e.g.,

```
HadamardMatrix[8]

HadamardMatrix[8].Inverse[HadamardMatrix[8]]

HadamardMatrix[5]
```

but can have zeroes as entries in addition to -1 and +1--and they exist for square matrices that are not 4*(positive integer).

Beyond a random search which is trivial and not a great method, does anyone know how to compute a Weighing matrix of size (general positive integer)?

Comment: n.b., this won't scale: `With[{size = 4},
 Select[Tuples[Tuples[{-1, 0, 1}, size], size], 
  Block[{diagQ = Transpose[#] . #, diagonals},
    diagonals = Diagonal[diagQ];
    DiagonalMatrixQ[diagQ] && 
     AllTrue[diagonals, # == First[diagonals] &]
    ] &]
 ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a straightforward approach for small (less than $4$) `n` and `w`:

```
ClearAll[a, A]; A = Table[a[i, j], {i, 4}, {j, 4}];
FindInstance[A . Transpose[A] == 2*IdentityMatrix[4] && Flatten[A] >= -1 && 
Flatten[A] <= 1, Flatten[A], Integers]
```

> `{{a[1, 1] -> -1, a[1, 2] -> -1, a[1, 3] -> 0, a[1, 4] -> 0,  a[2, 1] -> -1, a[2, 2] -> 1, a[2, 3] -> 0, a[2, 4] -> 0,  a[3, 1] -> 0, a[3, 2] -> 0, a[3, 3] -> -1, a[3, 4] -> 1,  a[4, 1] -> 0, a[4, 2] -> 0, a[4, 3] -> -1, a[4, 4] -> -1}}`

For many `n` and `k` a weighting matrix does not exist and the above code derives it. For example, `FindInstance[ A . Transpose[A] == 5*IdentityMatrix[4] && Flatten[A] >= -1 &&  Flatten[A] <= 1, Flatten[A], Integers]` results in `{}`.

Comment: Nice. I wish I'd thought of FindInstance.  I'll wait a couple days to accept as answerd to see if someone has a method that scales to larger n and w.